# Nested child component is not loaded/rendered

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have the following structure:

[image]

In `app-home` I have several components that doesn't get rendered, for instance a component named `<app-insightchart [applicationId]="applicationId"></app-insightchart>`. It isn't created nor loaded (I've got a lot of console.logs to verify :)).

The entire `app-home` HTML is loaded, but the components are not translated (their markup is untouched).
[image]

Now, if I instead put that chart component code in `app-details` it renders perfectly fine.

**Module definition**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CreateApplicationComponent } from './admin/create/create.component';
import { EditComponent } from './admin/edit/edit.component';
import { MembersComponent } from './admin/members/members.component';
import { SummaryChartComponent } from "./charts/summary/summary.component";
import { InsightChartComponent } from "./charts/insights/insightchart.component";
import { GroupCreateComponent } from './group-create/group-create.component';
import { GroupListComponent } from './group-list/group-list.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ApplicationDetailsComponent } from "./details/details.component";
import { ApplicationHomeComponent } from "./details/home/home.component";
import { NavbarComponent } from './details/navbar/navbar.component';
import { PipeModule } from "../../pipes/pipe.module";
import { ControlsModule } from "../_controls/controls.module";

const ourRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'application/group/create', component: GroupCreateComponent },
  {
    path: 'application/:applicationId',
    component: ApplicationDetailsComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        outlet: 'application-details-outlet',
        component: ApplicationHomeComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: 'application/:applicationId/members', component: MembersComponent },
  { path: 'application/:applicationId/edit', component: EditComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CreateApplicationComponent,
    EditComponent,
    MembersComponent,
    SummaryChartComponent,
    InsightChartComponent,
    GroupCreateComponent,
    GroupListComponent,
    ApplicationDetailsComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    PipeModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ControlsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(ourRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    CreateApplicationComponent,
    SummaryChartComponent,
    InsightChartComponent,
    GroupCreateComponent,
    GroupListComponent
  ]
})
export class ApplicationModule { }
```

What's going on?

Comment: Please add your module and routing files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your home component is not imported so it cannot be aware of the adjacent components - in effect its just ignoring it.

You have to load the home component directly here or into another module that is loaded here.  Currently they are contextually unaware of one another.

Comment: I updated the question to provide the entire module definition (including routes). Isn't it enough that it's loaded for the route definition?

Comment: its still the same answer man, you didn't import HomeComponent or didn't import the module where you do import and export it.  So the other components do not know what it is.

Comment: Yes, that was it. It started working when I added the component to the declarations section. Thanks!